# SVG usage in xamarin.forms

Tags: image, svg, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use the SVG image in my xamarin.forms application. Here I placed some SVG image in my PCL project and able to display that image. But what I want is, user able to tap on particular part of the image and the selected area should change its color.
For example: I am displaying the human body, if I selects the right hand on the image the color of that particular hand should be changed.

I am using `FFImageLoading` package and the code as following

```
<ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Source="mySample.cat.svg"/>
```

Comment: Maybe you can add the image to a `button`. And there is a `Pressing` event of button.The `Pressed` event occurs when a finger presses on a Button.You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#pressing-and-releasing-the-button.

Comment: @jackHua, thanks for the reply, I am able to handle the events, but not able to get how to change the colour of the svg image.

Comment: You can change the image when someone press on a Button. And set the origin image when releasing event occurs.